# How to hide and show a div, based on model condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I want to hide/show a div based on checkbox. Seems pretty simple. I store the value of checkbox in a model and use it in div ng-show. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div ng-app='visibleApp'>
    <div ng-controller='myController'>
         <input type="checkbox" name="hideBasicInfo" ng-model="hideBasicInfo">hide the basic information section
         <div ng-show="{{!hideBasicInfo}}">
             <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
             <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName"/></br>

             <label for="middleName">Middle Name:</label>
             <input type="text" name="middleName" ng-model="middleName"/></br>
             <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
             <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName"/>
         </div>
         <hr/>
         <div>
             <h4>Debug Information</h4>
             hideBasicInfo: {{hideBasicInfo}}<br/>
             !hideBasicInfo: {{!hideBasicInfo}}
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

JS file:

```
var visibleApp = angular.module('visibleApp',[]);

visibleApp.controller('myController', function($scope){
     $scope.data = "my data";
     $scope.hideBasicInfo = false; 
});
```

Thank you.

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8indaas/7uNSZ/3/)

Comment: You don't need the {{ }}

Answer (score 13, accepted):

almost there...

```
 <div ng-hide="hideBasicInfo">
    ...
 </div>
```

no template braces ( {{}} ) needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-show='One'>
 <p>Section One</p>
</div>

<div ng-show='Two'>
 <p>Section Two</p>
</div>

<div ng-show='Three'>
 <p>Section Three</p>
</div>

<!-- Navigation -->
<nav>
 <a href='#' ng-click='showOne'> Show Div One </a>
 <a href='#' ng-click='showTwo'> Show Div Two </a>
 <a href='#' ng-click='showThree'> Show Div Three </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: maybe an explanation would make the solution more obvious?

Comment: Just run these below code,
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
  <h3>1. Show</h3>
  <label>Show the square: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mustShow" /></label><br />
  <div ng-show="mustShow" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;"></div><br />
  <br />
  <h3>2. Hide</h3>
  <label>Hide the square: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mustHide" /></label><br />
  <div ng-hide="mustHide" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green;"></div>
</body>
</html>

Comment: he ngShow directive shows or hides the given HTML element based on the expression provided to the ngShow attribute. The element is shown or hidden by removing or adding the .ng-hide CSS class onto the element. The .ng-hide CSS class is predefined in AngularJS and sets the display style to none (using an !important flag). For CSP mode please add angular-csp.css to your html file (see ngCsp).

Answer (score 0):

```
Execute this code:`enter code here`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app>
  <h3>1. Show</h3>
  <label>Show the square: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mustShow" /></label><br />
  <div ng-show="mustShow" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;"></div><br />
  <br />
  <h3>2. Hide</h3>
  <label>Hide the square: <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mustHide" /></label><br />
  <div ng-hide="mustHide" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: green;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long, but it is expected.